# Perceptron model: Effect of the learning rate when all weights are initialized to zeros

Tags: neural-network, linear-algebra, trigonometry, perceptron

In Python Machine Learning 2rd book, related to the weight initialization step in the Perceptron, the author wrote:

[image: Python Machine Learning]

I'm not expert at Trigonometry and Algebra so I don't really understand how the angle between two vectors (is zero) relates to the effect of learning rate to the weights (when it's initialized to all zeros). Please help to connect the two points?

Comment: Same as https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26134/initialize-perceptron-weights-with-zero

Comment: That's exact what I asked for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each vector has a direction and a magnitude. When we multiply a vector to a constant the direction is not change. consider a=(1,0,0) and b =(2,0,0). clearly, both of them are in same direction.
Moreover, when two vectors are in the same direction the angle between them is zero. (Consider vectors as arrows in your mind)